# Need advice to run a unit test effectively on 14gb compressed data in dictionary form

Tags: software-testing, big-data

I've got 14GB of compressed data for a class assignment. I need to run a unit test on modules I've created to make use of the uncompressed data, which will be an object of nested dictionaries with the innermost dictionary having lists for its values.

Both my ideas and where I'm getting stuck:

1. My first idea was to have my unit test actually calculate the target assertion value, but it would be the same code as I'm testing so that isn't an effective test. Or maybe I'm wrong, I don't know.
2. I could calculate the target assertion value on a small dataset (say a single key:value pair but the value could be a large list or another large dictionary) using jupyter, but I've read that jupyter cannot load more than 100MB at a time.

I'm thinking the second idea is the way to go, but I need to know how I can run even the subsample without running against jupyter's memory limit.

Could anyone provide any hints to a rook? Or if there's another method, I'm also open to that.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.  I couldn't understand the first paragraph.  I understand that you want to run a unit test, but I don't understand what constraints that puts on the solution, or what a solution even is.  What are the requirements that any solution must satisfy? How will you evaluate proposed solutions?  What metrics will you use to measure how good a solution is?

Comment: When it is infeasible to process all of a dataset as a unit test, consider using an excerpt. If there is reason to assume the `assertion value [calculated] using Jupyter` is correct, that sounds worth a try: Why would `the value [being] large` be a problem? (This [sounds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) a question for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)